# Testing NATS-streaming in Kubernetes with minimal effort

Tags: go, kubernetes, nats.io, kubernetes-custom-resources, nats-streaming-server

I wanted to test a very basic application for NATS-streaming on Kubernetes. To do so, [I followed the commands from the official NATS-docs](https://docs.nats.io/nats-on-kubernetes/minimal-setup).

It basically comes down to running

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nats-io/k8s/master/nats-server/single-server-nats.yml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nats-io/k8s/master/nats-streaming-server/single-server-stan.yml
```

in a terminal with access to the cluster (it's a [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/)-cluster in my case).

I used [`stan.go`](https://github.com/nats-io/stan.go) as the NATS-streaming-client. Here is the code I tried to connect to the NATS-streaming-server:

```golang
package main

import stan "github.com/nats-io/stan.go"

func main() {
    sc, err := stan.Connect("stan", "test-client")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := sc.Publish("test-subject", []byte("This is a test-message!")); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
panic: nats: no servers available for connection

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/thilt/tmp/main.go:9 +0x15d
exit status 2
```

so I think another name was used for the cluster or something. If I use the provided example with `nats-box` from the docs.nats-link above, it also doesn't work! Where did I go wrong here?

I will happily provide more information, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [great example in stan.go docs](https://github.com/nats-io/stan.go/blob/master/examples/stan-pub/main.go#L82-L93):

```
// Connect to NATS
nc, err := nats.Connect(URL, opts...)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer nc.Close()

sc, err := stan.Connect(clusterID, clientID, stan.NatsConn(nc))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Can't connect: %v.\nMake sure a NATS Streaming Server is running at: %s", err, URL)
}
defer sc.Close()
```

Your error happens because by default stan connects to localhost address ([source code](https://github.com/nats-io/stan.go/blob/910e9bca44c8caf96e3e479874a589bf6c36e817/stan.go#L33)):

```
// DefaultNatsURL is the default URL the client connects to
DefaultNatsURL = "nats://127.0.0.1:4222"
```

Notice that povided above example overwrite this default connection.

Stan source code is short and easy to analyze. I really recommend you to try to analyze it and figure out what it does.

---

Now let's put it all together; here is a working example:

```
package main

import (
    nats "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
    stan "github.com/nats-io/stan.go"
)

func main() {
    // Create a NATS connection 
    nc, err := nats.Connect("nats://nats:4222")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Then pass it to the stan.Connect() call.
    sc, err := stan.Connect("stan", "me", stan.NatsConn(nc))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := sc.Publish("test-subject", []byte("This is a test-message!")); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```